# Google Chrome extension - create and remove a tab automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension that will launch an external script based on highlighted text.  So, far, the script works, except I am having issues closing the newly created window.

In my background.html, I have the following:

```
<script>
function executeScript(selection) {
  var queryText = 'script:' + selectedText;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: queryText});
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
  });
}
</script>
```

My problem is with the setup above, it closes the tab before the "url" loads, so it never executes the script.

If I take out the getSelected lines (lines 5-7), it opens the tab and runs the script perfectly.  I am trying to just get the syntax to close the tab automatically after it executes.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you're probably looking for some kind of `onLoad` event.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Javascript's `eval` function to execute the script in the background page directly rather than opening and closing a new tab?

Comment: because when the url goes of script:foo, it launches and passes the variable foo to the script.  I am trying to accomplish the same functionality I have with a firefox plugin within chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to close a tab after a script has run you should have the script send a "Close Me" request to background.html using `chrome.extension.sendRequest`.

You might be better off using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript), which allows you to pass a function (in which you could close the tab) which gets called after the script has finished running.

Comment: Basically, right now the tab flashes open then closes, but I need the script to wait until the "script:foo" url is loaded...

Comment: What kind of URL is "script:foo"? Do you mean "javascript:foo"?

Comment: no.  it is a custom uri that I have registered.  See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2b67d52a2d974418&hl=en if you want to see what I did...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post a followup question to this issue:

I want to make a Chrome Extension which passes on the URL (and eventually a selected Text) of a given Tab to my program (in OS X).

The problem is that Chrome closes the tab immediately after it opened it and does not really load the URL. The only way to make this happen is by inserting the alert-command, which is not practicable.

I also tried it with

> chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener

but it's the same result, and setTimeout does not seem to be registered at all.

My code:

> chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab)
>   {
>         chrome.tabs.create({url:"myApp:add?url="+encodeURIComponent(tab.url)},
>   function(tab){
>                 alert("Your URL is added to myApp");
>         chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id); 
>         }); 
>   });

I would need the exact same result, only without the alert box.... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: yourUrl },function(tab){
                                                setTimeout(function(){chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);}, 200);
                                    });
```